# Oracle Instant Client installation woes - "HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value"

Tags: oracle, fedora, sqlplus

When I run sqlplus I get the following error:

```
#sqlplus
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus  
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value  
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible
```

I've just installed the oracle instant client on fedora 12 by doing the following:

I downloaded the rpms from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html

- oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm
- oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm
- oracle-instantclient11.2-jdbc-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm
- oracle-instantclient11.2-odbc-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm
- oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm
- oracle-instantclient11.2-tools-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm

I then installed them all using rpm

In addition I added this to my /etc/bashrc file and restarted the shell:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client  
export LD_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib/
```

OS: Fedora 12, 2.6.32.16-150.fc12.i686.PAE

This is a VMWare vm - that doesn't have access to the internet.

Perhaps I be using the i686 versions?

Thanks SF

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was to set http_proxy to blank:

```
export http_proxy=
```

Then run SQL Plus

Answer (score 2):

sqlplus uses the http_proxy and no_proxy environment variables to determine if proxy is used.  To bypass the proxy settings then both these values need to be unset.

```
unset http_proxy
unset no_proxy
```

or

```
export http_proxy=
export no_proxy=
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had set my password to the wrong value in profile.d/proxy.sh